# Why is a specific variable causing html to print out

Tags: php, wordpress, background-image

I am trying to display some images in my wordpress site. I am trying to make the background div and image via `style=""`

So when I do this:

```
<?php
if(has_post_thumbnail($property->ID)){
    $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($property->ID,array(300,220),array('class' => "post_thumbnail"));
}else{
    $image = $image_url = '';
}
?>
<div class="property_photo" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_url;?>') no-repeat;">
</div>
```

The photo is not displaying anymore and it's printing `') no-repeat;">` where the image should display. When I use a variable without an "_" in the name, it doesn't print anything. So to avoid that I tried `$image = $image_url = '';` to get around that.

Is this is a simple syntax problem or is there something in the php that is causes this? It doesn't seem like syntax because when I use other variable it does not do this.

Comment: Trying dumping the value of `$image_url`. Seems it's not just the URL, but rather some HTML.

Comment: @Mark Parnell interesting, when I do that it says "string(173) and the image actually shows up. Along with the unwanted html of course

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function is returning HTML, not a URL. You need to either change the function to only return a URL (or use a different function which does that), or change your HTML to put the image inside the `div` instead of setting it as a background image.

Comment: I've tried many combinations and various functions. I'm still confused how this      <?php
     if(has_post_thumbnail($property->ID)){
         $image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail($property->ID,array(300,220),array('class' => "post_thumbnail"));
     }
     echo $image_url;
     ?>
     <div class="property_photo" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $image_url;?>') no-repeat;">
     </div>
     ?> posts the image after the ifstatement but not in the style tag. I've even tried adding site_url to the style tag php

Comment: Also when I view the source, it's displaying the proper url path

Comment: <div class="property_photo" style="background-image:url('<?php if (has_post_thumbnail($property->ID)){
           echo get_the_post_thumbnail(
           $property->ID,
           array(200,200),
           array('class' => "post_thumbnail")
           );
          }
          ?>') no-repeat">

     </div> is the same problem

Comment: It doesn't show the image when you try and put it in the style attribute because it's in the value of the attribute. `<div style="<p>some text</p>">` won't ever display "some text".